# Is this negation right?

Tags: negation, auxiliary-verbs

I read the following sentence on the Internet:

> One of the biggest problems facing our brave space explorers as we extend our reach into the Solar System involves **not** the physical body but the mind.

I know that the negation is formed by an auxiliary verb + not. I'm confused because my English teacher told me that this is right

If this is right, can anyone then explain me why?

Comment: It's legitimate.  Can you explain why it's not?

Comment: I don't know that's why I asked

Comment: The noun phrase _the physical body_ is what's negated here, and since it's a noun phrase, the negator _not_ is used right before it. You put _not_ after an auxiliary verb when it's negating a verb phrase -- verb phrases have auxiliaries, but noun phrases don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase there is equivalent to

> involves the mind, not the physical body.

When written there, you can see that *not* is being used to indicate alternatives, and one of them is negated. It's not modifying the verb, so no auxiliary very is used. It could instead have been written with a negated verb:

> does not involve the physical body, but instead involves the mind.

but this is more wordy and repeats "involve" unnecessarily.

Putting the negated noun first emphasizes the fact that this object is being negated or excluded, and is often done when that object is the normal assumption. In the case of your example, people might naively assume that the biggest problems of long-distance space travel are from physical problems (food, air, radiation, etc.), but they're claiming that the mental problems (long-term isolation, personal relations with crewmates, etc.) are actually more significant.